# Language problems with biblatex and babel

Tags: biblatex, errors, babel, ieeetran

I am trying to use `biblatex` with `IEEEtran` and `babel`, however I am having an error: `Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language ENGLISH yet.`. With regular `Bibtex` everything works as usual. The MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[strict,autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex-ieee/biblatex-ieee.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would `\usepackage[english]{babel}` help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error seems indeed to be caused by the combination `biblatex`/`babel`/`IEEEtran` -- your example (with an appropriate `.bib` file)  works with the `article` class. A workaround is to fake an `ENGLISH` (uppercase) dialect for the `english` language.

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
\adddialect\l@ENGLISH\l@english
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[strict,autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying this example (except using `lipsum` instead of `blindtext`) on TexLive 2014 - and it still spits out the old "Package babel Warning: You haven't loaded the language ENGLISH yet"; regardless if I use `\adddialect\l@ENGLISH\l@english` or `\let\l@ENGLISH\l@english`. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `IEEEtran.cls` changes the meaning of `\markboth` applying yet another `\MakeUppercase`, to which

```
\protect\foreignlanguage{english}{%
  \protect\bbl@restore@actives\MakeUppercase{\refname}}
```

is passed, resulting in LaTeX trying to do

```
\foreignlanguage{ENGLISH}
```

which gives the error. This is caused by `\printbibliography`, but is not a responsibility of `biblatex`, only by a not so wise redefinition of `\markboth`

One can notice that `\refname` is already passed to `\MakeUppercase`.

You have two choices:

1. change the bad redefinition of `\markboth`:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\markboth#1#2{%
     \def\leftmark{\@IEEEcompsoconly{\sffamily}#1}%
     \def\rightmark{\@IEEEcompsoconly{\sffamily}#2}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   The IEEEtran definition has `\MakeUppercase{#1}` and `\MakeUppercase{#2}`.
2. enable a fake `ENGLISH` language referring to `english`:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \let\l@ENGLISH\l@english
   \makeatother
   ```

Just put one of the two pieces of code in the preamble of your document. Probably the second one is the safest.

Comment: Thanks! The second solution is really the safest, and similar to the one provided by lockstep. I will prefer the lockstep solution since it uses a `babel` command and not the more generic `\let`.

Comment: @cacamailg Yes, probably the people at IEEE would remove your definition, just to find them in trouble; so they would remove the call to `babel` and also to `csquotes`, ruining your pretty formatting. :(

Comment: Yes, and they would also remove `biblatex` :(.

Answer (score 2):

Check your bib file for the line which google, or journal, often add when you export a citation.

```
language={english}
```

delete it, then delte the .bbl and the .aux, then recompile

Comment: In the `.bib` file?

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying these examples with a fresh TexLive 2014; I had been using the `\let\l@ENGLISH\l@english` fix for a while in TexLive 2011 with success, but now with 2014 the same document gave me the dreaded warning:

```
Package babel Warning: You haven't loaded the language ENGLISH yet
(babel)                I'll proceed, but expect unexpected results.
(babel)                Reported on input line 38.
```

This is the example I used, which now compiles in TexLive 2014 without the warning:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{trace}
% \traceon

\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
% \adddialect\l@ENGLISH\l@english
% \global\let\l@ENGLISH\l@english
\let\l@ENGLISH\relax
\show\l@english
\show\l@ENGLISH
\typeout{BABEL TEST:}
\ifx \csname l@english\endcsname\relax
  \typeout{l@english here}
\fi
\ifx \csname l@ENGLISH\endcsname\relax
  \typeout{l@ENGLISH here}
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[strict,autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The weird thing is - in TexLive 2014 versions, the `\let\l@ENGLISH\l@english` actually *triggers* the warning to appear. I used `trace` to scan a bit, and here is an overview:

Eventually, when Latex needs to print a section title it will call `\foreignlanguage`, e.g.:

```
\foreignlanguage  #1#2->\begingroup \foreign@language {#1}#2\endgroup 
#1<-ENGLISH
#2<-\protect \bbl@restore@actives \protect \MakeUppercase  {REFERENCES}
{\begingroup}
{entering semi simple group (level 12) at line 29}
```

In the course of its execution, we eventually come to this conditional, which takes the false branch when `\let\l@ENGLISH\l@english` is in effect:

```
\@ifundefined #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname \relax \expandafter \@
firstoftwo \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo \fi 
#1<-\bbl@tempe ENGLISH
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\bbl@tempe ->l@
{\ifx}
{false}
{\expandafter}
{\fi}
```

Let's look at `\@ifundefined` more closely:

```
\expandafter %
\ifx \csname #1\endcsname \relax %
  \expandafter \@firstoftwo %
\else %
  \expandafter \@secondoftwo %
\fi
```

So in this case, the `\ifx` basically checks if the <s>expanded</s> (see comments below) versions of `\l@ENGLISH` and `\relax` are the same; and since `\relax` is unexpandable (a Tex primitive?), obviously the `\ifx` will be false for any value of `\l@ENGLISH` different from `\relax`, such as `\l@english` (with contents being just `\char"0`).

So the solution for TexLive 2014 is either to `\let\l@ENGLISH\relax` - or, not address it at all (which is a bit strange to me, because in that case, \l@ENGLISH is `\show`n as `undefined` [not as the command/macro/token, though], and `\ifx` doesn't see `\relax` and `\undefined` as the same:

```
? i
insert>\ifx\relax\undefined\typeout{A}\else\typeout{B}\fi
B
```

)

Well, hope this was it with this problem, then - probably it's time to write another TexLive version conditional ([Getting Texlive version in pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205210/getting-texlive-version-in-pdflatex))...

Comment: The redefinition of `\markboth` that I suggested is independent of `babel` and works also in TL 2014. The problem seems to be that the new version of `babel` has changed a bit its working.

Comment: Note that `\expandafter\ifx\csname l@ENGLISH\endcsname\relax` just forms the `\l@ENGLISH` token and then `\ifx` compares it with `\relax`. It *doesn't* expand `\l@ENGLISH`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @egreg - I honestly didn't try the `\markboth` approach in the past, I liked the simplicity of the `\let` one `:)` - so thanks for that mention, and the note about expansion. Cheers!