# Unable to get rid of error babel: You haven't defined the language en yet?

Tags: babel

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet
```

I am getting the above error - no matter what I do... I have tried everything from the other answers and am sure now that its not related:
[Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97814/package-babel-error-you-havent-loaded-the-option-english-yet),
[Language problems with biblatex and babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88861/language-problems-with-biblatex-and-babel).
Nothing is working. These are the errors:

> ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.81 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.89 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language English yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.97 \select@language{English}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.105 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language jpn yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.129 \select@language{jpn}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.137 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.145 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.153 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.161 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
>   See the babel package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.169 \select@language{en}
>   Your command will be ignored, type  to proceed
>   )

It doesn’t matter if I have this line or not:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ MWE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
\documentclass{../frontiersstyle.sty/frontiersENG}

\usepackage{url,lineno}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
\linenumbers

\copyrightyear{}
\pubyear{}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{../frontiersstyle.sty/frontiersinSCNS&ENG}

\cite{katsuyama_functional_2010}

\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the entire preamble. There might be some package conflicts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Moreover, it is hard to tell what is going wrong without looking at a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Remove the `.aux` files, type `\usepackage[english]{babel}` and retry. The error is due to a preceding attempt with wrong options.

Comment: @egreg: I doubt it. You wouldn't get languages "en", "jpn" and "English" (uppercase) with the normal babel options. It is probably a faulty "language switching" command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Possible; a minimal example is surely necessary.

Comment: @remus                                            `\documentclass{../frontiersstyle.sty/frontiersENG} 
\usepackage{url,lineno}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
\linenumbers

\copyrightyear{}
\pubyear{}`

Comment: @egreg This I have done - in every possible combination

Comment: @ashley Well, doing `\selectlanguage{jpn}` or `\selectlanguage{en}` is invalid. Please, try making a minimal example.

Comment: Where could I find 'frontiers' template?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the bib file..

Comment: @remus http://www.frontiersin.org/design/zip/Frontiers%20LaTeX%20%28Science%2C%20Health%20and%20Engineering%29%20V2.4%20-%20with%20Supplementary%20material.zip

Comment: @egreg your answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88861/language-problems-with-biblatex-and-babel does not work for me - though I think its on the right track

Comment: I copy/pasted your preamble into frontiers template and I could not reproduce the babel error.

Comment: Could you give us your tex files (post them somewhere publicly)? It's important to reproduce the bug in order to find a fix.

Comment: @ashley I won't look at this any more, unless you add to the ***question*** (not in comments) some code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @egreg I added to the question

Comment: I had a similar issue and I solved it by removing `language = {en}` in `bib` file (or changing them to `language = {english}`).

Comment: I had the same error. The solution was to delete `language = {eng}` from the bib entry, as @PiotrMigdal said.

Comment: Strange that the question is closed. It described very much my problem. In my case it was a missing texlive-lang-german package on Ubuntu that caused the error message.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a book template (Los_Academicos) with English language selected, with error for Spanish not defined. Solved installing texlive-lang-spanish. (`sudo apt install texlive-lang-spanish`).

Answer (score 11):

When you change what `babel` languages you use, it's good to remove the `.aux` file which contains things LaTeX saves from run to run, since it will contain lines that only work with the babel settings you had before.

If you rerun after removing the `.aux` file and get errors anyway they will have linenumbers, maybe pointing to lines where you do something like

```
\selectlanguage{SOMELANGUAGE}
```

where SOMELANGUAGE isn't mentioned in your babel settings.

From your error messages we can see you have called English "english" sometimes, and just "en" sometimes. The latter is incorrect. We can also see you at some time have tried to include Japanese. There is a question about writing Japanese [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex).

Comment: The presence of `\select@language` makes it highly unlikely that it refers to the main document, but rather to the `.aux` file.

Comment: True. I mostly wanted to alert ashley to the fact that these are strings that originally are from the document.

Comment: Not changing languages at any point, include accents but that's about it language wise. I would like to remove babel all together, but then it fails to compile at all.

Comment: When it seems to not work "no matter what you do", there is a risk of changing several things at the same time, and not noticing the effect.

Remove babel, since that's what you want. Remove the `.aux` files. (If you are unsure if you've removed all intermediary files, copy your TeX file to a new directory, to start from a clean slate.) Rerun. Then state more precisely what happens then, when it "fails to compile".

Comment: @pst I removed babel and .aux and reran - the errors remain so it must be defining it somewhere else other than my main doc..

Comment: you can simply try this : sudo apt install texlive-lang-german

Comment: I had the same problem, the \selectlanguage{en} command was in the bbl file. It seems that Zotero put the "en" in the respective entry when autoimporting references, exported it into my bib file and then the compiler put in the command. Not sure why I never had this problem before, perhaps it was natbib that puts the command there (which I normally do not use)? In any case, I removed the entry from my Zotero library entry, updated the bib file, and deleted the bbl file. It was tedious, but that solved it. There should be a less tedious way though.

Comment: @user510186 please consider adding this comment as an answer. This was useful to me. The problem can be hidden or appear depending on one’s bib style, I think.