# babel - define language synonym

Tags: bibtex, babel, languages, revtex

I use `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, but I am keeping getting error:

```
Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language EN yet.
```

while parsing bibliography with `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` (curiously enough, for some other bibliography styles I don't get this problem).

I've discovered that in some `bib` entries there are lines

```
language = {en},
```

Changing `en` to `english` does solve the problem.
However, as I get the `bib` file generated from other tool (Mendeley) it would be annoying.

Is there a way to define language `en` as a synonym of `english`?

Note:

There is a similar question [Unable to get rid of error babel: You haven't defined the language en yet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168675/unable-to-get-rid-of-error-babel-you-havent-defined-the-language-en-yet), but it is closed as unclear.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Renyi1961}

    \bibliography{notwrk}

\end{document}
```

And `notwrk.bib`

```
@inproceedings{Renyi1961,
author = {R\'{e}nyi, Alfr\'{e}d},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics and Probability, Volume 1: Contributions to the Theory of Statistics},
issn = {0097-0433},
language = {en},
publisher = {The Regents of the University of California},
title = {{On Measures of Entropy and Information}},
url = {http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512181},
year = {1961}
}
```

Comment: Also this question is unclear, mainly because an example is missing.

Comment: @egreg What is unclear in "[In babel], [i]s there a way to define language `en` as a synonym of `english`?"? In any case, as of now I am working on a phd thesis, so it would take me time to create a "minimal (not) working example".

Comment: How are we supposed to reproduce the issue? Just a minimal preamble, the bibliography style, a citation and an entry that creates the problem. I tried to make a M(n)WE, but got no error.

Comment: I added example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a full aliasing system, because it acts just on `\selectlanguage`, but it should be sufficient for your purpose. A full system would need deep surgery in `babel`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Renyi1961,
author = {R\'{e}nyi, Alfr\'{e}d},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics 
  and Probability, Volume 1: Contributions to the Theory of Statistics},
issn = {0097-0433},
language = {en},
publisher = {The Regents of the University of California},
title = {{On Measures of Entropy and Information}},
url = {http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512181},
year = {1961}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\usepackage{doi}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\ORIGselectlanguage}{\selectlanguage}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\selectlanguage}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{alias@\string#1}
    {\ORIGselectlanguage{#1}}
    {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\ORIGselectlanguage{\@nameuse{alias@#1}}}\x}%
}
\newcommand{\definelanguagealias}[2]{%
  \@namedef{alias@#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\definelanguagealias{en}{english}


\begin{document}

    \cite{Renyi1961}

    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` trick is just to make the example self-contained, you don't need it and you can use the normal `.bib` file you have.

---

Following a suggestion of Javier Bezos, patching `\bbl@fixname` seems better, because it also works with all language changing commands.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Renyi1961,
  author = {R{\'{e}}nyi, Alfr{\'{e}}d},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics 
               and Probability, Volume 1: Contributions to the Theory of Statistics},
  issn = {0097-0433},
  language = {en},
  publisher = {The Regents of the University of California},
  title = {{On Measures of Entropy and Information}},
  url = {http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512181},
  year = {1961}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{doi}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\makeatletter
\let\ORIbbl@fixname\bbl@fixname
\def\bbl@fixname#1{%
  \@ifundefined{languagealias@\expandafter\string#1}
    {\ORIbbl@fixname#1}
    {\edef\languagename{\@nameuse{languagealias@#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\definelanguagealias}[2]{%
  \@namedef{languagealias@#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\definelanguagealias{en}{english}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Renyi1961}

    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works! For the full file I had to add also `\definelanguagealias{EN}{english}`, as it seems to be case-sensitive.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Yes, it is. But it's just a matter of adding the necessary aliases once the need arises.

Comment: This solution does not work for the `IEEEtran` style, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527949/babel-define-language-synonym-for-ieeetran

Comment: @stefanct `IEEEtran.bst` is not the same as `apsrev4-1`. There's no reason to expect they work the same.

Comment: Well, no, not exactly... (OTOH the patch does not do anything natbib-specific AFAICS) but this question+solution was still the next best thing and thus I ended up here before posting my own question and thus adding that comment/link seems useful to me.