# babel - define language synonym (for IEEEtran)

Tags: bibtex, babel, ieeetran

I have a problem almost identically to this [old other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199254/babel-define-language-synonym). The differences are that I am using Zotero and the IEEEtran bib style.

Zotero basically does the same thing as Mendeley, i.e. producing `language` fields in the `.bib` with the value `en` etc. So this difference is insignificant to this question and I state it here only for search engine users.

The IEEEtran bib style emits some code that apparently checks if the `language`'s value is a defined babel language. If that's not the case it produces a warning:

```
** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been
** loaded for the language `en'. Using the pattern for
```

This comes from the following code:

```
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
```

Just like in the other question I would like to use the bib style without changing the `.bib` file. However, the workaround/solution of the other question does not work with IEEEtran.

MWE (w/o the defunct workaround for natbib):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Renyi1961,
    author = {R\'{e}nyi, Alfr\'{e}d},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics 
      and Probability, Volume 1: Contributions to the Theory of Statistics},
    issn = {0097-0433},
    language = {en},
    publisher = {The Regents of the University of California},
    title = {{On Measures of Entropy and Information}},
    url = {http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512181},
    year = {1961}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Renyi1961}

    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you export using the BBT plugin, the language `en` in the item will be exported as `langid = {english}`. Would that make a change for your case?

Comment: I guess you mean when exporting to bib**la**tex? Because I am using BBT but it generates `language` fields that don't have their value processed AFAICT.

Comment: I did mean that, but if there's a more sensible way to export languages for bibtex, feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues and I'll get it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** Sorry, my answer does not solve the problem. I was assuming the selection was done with `babel`, but it turns out this is not true. However, I won't delete it because it could be useful in other cases.

**Original answer**

Here is a quick hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}

% The hack:
\makeatletter
\let\old@fixname\bbl@fixname
\def\bbl@fixname#1{%
  \@ifundefined{babelalias#1}%
    {\old@fixname{#1}}%
    {\edef\languagename{\csname babelalias#1\endcsname}}}
\makeatother

% The synonymous:
\newcommand{\babelaliasen}{english}
\newcommand{\babelaliasda}{danish}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{da}

\languagename --- \chaptername

\selectlanguage{en}

\languagename --- \chaptername

\end{document}
```

Not very elegant, but it seems to work. An interface for BCP 47 codes is under study, and very likely it will be available in a couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

You can do better, see the other thread.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Renyi1961,
  author = {R{\'{e}}nyi, Alfr{\'{e}}d},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics 
               and Probability, Volume 1: Contributions to the Theory of Statistics},
  issn = {0097-0433},
  language = {en},
  publisher = {The Regents of the University of California},
  title = {{On Measures of Entropy and Information}},
  url = {http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512181},
  year = {1961}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{doi}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\let\ORIbbl@fixname\bbl@fixname
\def\bbl@fixname#1{%
  \@ifundefined{languagealias@\expandafter\string#1}
    {\ORIbbl@fixname#1}
    {\edef\languagename{\@nameuse{languagealias@#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\definelanguagealias}[2]{%
  \@namedef{languagealias@#1}{#2}%
}
\let\BIBforeignlanguage\foreignlanguage
\makeatother

\definelanguagealias{en}{english}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Renyi1961}

    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The trick is inducing `IEEEtran` to use a better command than `\language\l@<language>`, namely `\foreignlanguage{<language>}{...}`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this seem to be simple TeX macros to define an alias, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@en{\l@english}
\makeatother
```

However, I am not sure if that solve the issue completely without regressions. It **does** load the correct hyphenation settings though. Also, I was not able to declare a suitable replacement for the `\definelanguagealias` command (either it was producing errors when defined with TeX primitives, or it was not creating the aliases correctly for babel/IEEEtran to pick up).

I'd be happy to select a more elegant suggestion as correct answer...